# Best practice for uploading multiple images from client to server

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am uploading multiple images from my client browser `(Aws s3 direct form upload/stream),` up to `25 images` at once.

Before I upload the images I am compressing them to make them smaller.

But now I am not sure if I should upload all images at once or once by one using ***recursion***

Example 1, looping through my images and uploading them all at once

```
var imagesUploaded = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < _this.imgArray.length; i++) {

        var params = {
          Key: 'images/' + id + '/' + _this.imgArray[i].name,
          ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
          Body: _this.imgArray[i],
          ACL: 'public-read'
        };

        bucket.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            //Run callback when all images are uploaded
            imagesUploaded.push("dummy"); //Just to end loop when all images are done
            if (imagesUploaded.length === _this.imgArray.length) {
              //Done uploading all.
              callback();
            }
          }
        });

      }
```

Example 2, using recursion. Upload one image at the time and start the next upload once previous is done.

```
func recursionUpload() {

.. some other code

var s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01', region: 'us-west-2'});
var params = {
  Bucket: 'bucket',
  Key: 'example2.txt',
  Body: 'Uploaded text using the promise-based method!'
};
var putObjectPromise = s3.putObject(params).promise();
putObjectPromise.then(function(data) {
  console.log('Success');

  //Upload next image
  recursionUpload()


}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});


}
```

I feel that example 1 is much faster since it will upload multiple images at the same time, but I am affraid that it can take too much memory form the browser. So which example is "best practise"

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is using a queue. This would allow putting new files to it even while an upload is already running.

```
var queue = [];

function put(file) {
    queue.push(file);
}

function next() {
    return queue.shift();
}

function start() {
    var nextFile;
    while((nextFile = next()) !== undefined) {
        // upload nextFile
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) for that:

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: "2006-03-01"});

const uploadImages = function uploadImages(images) {
  return Promise.all(images.map((img) => {
    const params = {
      Bucket: "your-bucket-name",
      Key: img.FileName,
      Body: img.Data
    };
    return s3.putObject(params).promise();
  }));
};

uploadImages(_this.imgArray)
  .then((responses) => {
    console.log(responses);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err.message);
  });
```

Answer (score -3):

Recursion is usually best avoided because it tends to either make a program run out of memory or to having it interrupted when it hits a recursion limit.

Uploading (many) files is best done with ftp.

Comment: How can it make a program run out of memory? The whole point of using recursion is to make sure that only *one* image gets uploaded at the time, once that is done it uploads the next image ie much less memory needed. And I cant use ftp. I am using aws s3 js sdk to do direct form uploads

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)  Uploading one image after another is a problem one would have to go to really weird lengths to use recursion to solve it --- or call it artificially employ recursion upon a linear problem that doesn´t require any recursion at all.